# (byebug) status 200 *** ArgumentError Exception: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

In the [stripe docs](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/creating-a-payments-page) I see some ruby code that conditionally returns a status 400, status 200 etc.

```rb
# Using Sinatra.
require 'sinatra'
require 'stripe'

set :port, 4242

# Set your secret key. Remember to switch to your live secret key in production!
# See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
Stripe.api_key = 'sk_test_51HYHSFGtUKse83O9J4QeAib3cp8sHzGaOQRrnwvnghEzuYQKUCKEP3CHE3AIHe5ModevMK7TVAUCyJU0ADSwIUoX00qxZmBI9r'

# Uncomment and replace with a real secret. You can find your endpoint's
# secret in your webhook settings.
# webhook_secret = 'whsec_...'

post '/webhook' do
  payload = request.body.read
  sig_header = request.env['HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE']

  event = nil

  # Verify webhook signature and extract the event.
  # See https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/signatures for more information.
  begin
    event = Stripe::Webhook.construct_event(
      payload, sig_header, webhook_secret
    )
  rescue JSON::ParserError => e
    # Invalid payload.
    status 400
    return
  rescue Stripe::SignatureVerificationError => e
    # Invalid Signature.
    status 400
    return
  end

  if event['type'] == 'payment_intent.succeeded'
    payment_intent = event['data']['object']
    handle_successful_payment_intent(payment_intent)
  end

  status 200
end

def handle_successful_payment_intent(payment_intent)
  # Fulfill the purchase.
  puts payment_intent.to_s
end
```

Is the literal `status 200` supposed to be valid ruby code, or pseudocode that the programmer needs to change to whatever they want to have happen when a status 400 occurs? (i.e. should the literal `status 400`, `status 200` etc be deleted?)

The reason for asking is because when the code gets to the point where it runs `status 200`, it returns:

```
(byebug) status 200
*** ArgumentError Exception: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`status` method](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra#setting-body-status-code-and-headers) can be used to set the returned HTTP status code of an action in [Sinatra](http://sinatrarb.com/), which is the web framework used in the example you quoted.

Given that Sinatra is a different web framework from Rails, this works different here. With Rails, the equivalent method call (in this case) would be [`head`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Head.html#method-i-head)

```
head 400
```

Note that a lot of other accessors used in the example work differently in Rails, including getting a header value of the request, reading the request body, and setting up e controller and routes.

Comment: Thanks for the very helpful answer. Just for completeness, does `head xxx` work with every status code?

Comment: Yes, you can set any numeric status code or its symbolic name.